# ASP.NET: Is it possible to pass Request.Form to a function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I receive most of my variables between my pages using **Request.Form("foo")** in my web application. Is it possible to pass entire **Request.Form** to a function and then extract my data using like this?

```
public string extract(myRequest){
  //blah blah
  return processed_data
}
```

If yes, What's the type of **myRequest**?

Comment: Move the cursor over Form (HttpContext.Current.Request.Form). Press F12. You'll see the type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it's possible. [`Request.Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) is a [`NameValueCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx). I suggest reading up on [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

It certainly is. The type is a [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx):

```
public string extract(NameValueCollection form) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, It's of type `FormCollection`, which inherits from `NameValueCollection`

Answer (score 1):

Using the [example in the documentaion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx)

```
public string extract(NameValueCollection myRequest) {
    int loop1;
    StringBuilder processed_data= new StringBuilder();
    // Get names of all forms into a string array.
    String[] arr1 = myRequest.AllKeys;
    for (loop1 = 0; loop1 < arr1.Length; loop1++) 
    {
        data.Append("Form: " + arr1[loop1] + "<br>");
    }
    return processed_data.ToString();
}
```